# Mongo db Load balancer stop balancing due to Config server Lock.

Tags: mongodb, load-balancing

In our production system, we have shard cluster with -

2 shards (each one is replica set of primary + secondary + arbiter)

3 Config servers

4 mongoS instances

A couple of days back, we faced a network outrage in which a secondary failed to connect to its corresponding primary. This issue was resolved in some time but mongo balancer is stuck from that point of time.

All of the data is being moved to a single shard and nothing is transferred. In mongoS logs, we monitored that lock was acquired by a mongoS instance but not released till date

configsvr> db.locks.find({state:2}).pretty()

```
{

"_id" : "balancer",

"process" : "mongosHost3:27017:1462857366:-506678190",

"state" : 2,

"ts" : ObjectId("57c29902a443254e2d8e1b27"),

"when" : ISODate("2016-08-28T07:55:46.350Z"),

"who" : "mongosHost3:27017:1462857366:-506678190:Balancer:37654778",

"why" : "doing balance round"

}
```

I checked the mongo logs from this MongoS server and found this repeating in the logs for last two days.

I SHARDING [LockPinger] cluster confserv_1.xyz.com:27017,confserv_2.xyz.com:27017,confserv_3.xyz.com:27017 pinged successfully at 2016-08-30T06:23:31.483+0530 by distributed lock pinger 'confserv_1.xyz.com:27017,confserv_2.xyz.com:27017,confserv_3.xyz.com:27017/mongosHost3:27017:1462857366:-506678190', sleeping for 30000ms

This is coming for last two days.

We checked DBHash on all config server that is in Sync.

Could you please help why this issue is happening and we can resolve it.